# Use style functions for material-ui components besides Box

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm just starting with Material UI. Thanks for bearing with me.

I know you can use things like `<Box mx={2}>` out-of-the-box (ha). So if I wanted to put a margin around, say, a `TextField`, I could wrap it in a box.

Is there a simple way to set up my app's theme so that **any** component can use those style function props? (`m`, `p`, `display`, etc)

So that I could to `<TextField mx={2}/>` without having to wrap it in a `Box`.

The [docs](https://material-ui.com/system/basics/#theming) imply that you can do this:
(the example uses `ThemeProvider` from `styled-components` but I'm *assuming* that MUI's `ThemeProvider` works the same way???)

```js
import React from 'react'
import { ThemeProvider } from 'styled-components'

const theme = {
  spacing: 4,
  palette: {
    primary: '#007bff',
  },
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      {/* children */}
    </ThemeProvider>
  )
}
```

I've tried this but it crashes from the `TextField's` `my` prop:

```js
import { createMuiTheme, TextField, ThemeProvider } from '@material-ui/core';

// Greatly simplified version of my component
const App = () => <TextField my={2}/> 

let theme = createMuiTheme({})

export default () =>
  <ThemeProvider theme={ theme }>
    <App/>
  </ThemeProvider>;
```

I can do something like this and it works:

```js
function App() {
  const Input = styled(TextField)(compose(spacing))

  return <Input my={3}/>
}
```

But then I'd have to `compose` my components every time I want to do use the style functions.

Comment: Ok, so the answer is that what I'm asking for can't be done?

Comment: Thanks. Is "you can't do it" a legitimate thing for you to post as an answer so I can mark this answered?

Comment: I've converted my comments (and expanded on them) to an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [docs](https://material-ui.com/system/basics/#theming) are showing how the theme can parameterize the Box features (e.g. such that a spacing unit is 4px instead of 8px) -- the theme doesn't do anything to enable those features.

Material-UI is intending to [support @material-ui/system features on core components in v5](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/15561), but that is still months away.

Your main options are doing something like you showed in your example (though you should move `const Input = styled(TextField)(compose(spacing))` to the top-level rather than doing this within render of App). You could put this in a separate file and import this component instead of `TextField` whenever you want to use those features. For instance:

**MyTextField.js**

```
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";
import { styled } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import { compose, spacing } from "@material-ui/system";

export default styled(TextField)(compose(spacing));
```

**App.js**

```
import React from "react";
import TextField from "./MyTextField";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <TextField variant="outlined" label="Material-UI system demo" />
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit Material-UI system demo (forked)]

Another option is to use `Box` with the [clone prop](https://material-ui.com/components/box/#overriding-material-ui-components) and wrap the component you want to style. For instance:

```
import React from "react";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";
import Box from "@material-ui/core/Box";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Box my={3} clone>
        <TextField variant="outlined" label="Box demo" />
      </Box>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit Box demo]

You can also use the `component` prop of `Box`:

```
import React from "react";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";
import Box from "@material-ui/core/Box";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Box my={3} component={TextField} variant="outlined" label="Box demo" />
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit Box demo (forked)]

Related answers:

- [Material-UI Grid does not hide whe use Display](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58189940/material-ui-grid-does-not-hide-whe-use-display/58192229#58192229)
- [Dynamic icon size in Material-UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62784041/dynamic-icon-size-in-material-ui/62786876#62786876)
- [Box vs className vs style for vertical spacing in Material UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62562157/box-vs-classname-vs-style-for-vertical-spacing-in-material-ui/62563326#62563326)
- [Reusable component using theme-based Box features](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63382653/reusable-component-using-theme-based-box-features/63383721#63383721)
- [Using Material-UI Box Component with the Drawer Compoment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59946751/using-material-ui-box-component-with-the-drawer-compoment/59952025#59952025)
- [How to use override Button using Box component in Material-UI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60970312/how-to-use-override-button-using-box-component-in-material-ui/60973098#60973098)